# Check if the filesystem supports hardlinks

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm writing a backup script, which uses hard links to not consume space for unmodified files.

I'd like to check if a given file system (as determined from a specific directory) supports hard links at the *start* of the script - otherwise, it could get half-way through (copying multiple files) before the first hard link needs creating, causing the script drops out with an exception (which I could recover by reverting changes or silently changing hard links to full copies, but I don't really want either - I'd just rather not start if it's going to hit this issue).

So, how do I check if the file system supports hard links if the only available input is a string containing a directory location (eg `"F:\\Backups"` or similar)?

Failing that, is there a nice way to check the *type* of file system that a particular directory is on?
I suppose could just pull that and then work out if it's supported or not from there?

Comment: Could you create a "dummy" symlink at the very start of your script, if that throws then you know it's not supported?

Comment: @Anon That would work, I'm sure, but it just doesn't feel like a very "clean" way to do it.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to try.  Note that NTFS supports hard links, but they're very rarely used and so are likely to be confusing to users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd tackle this problem this way: There are 3 alternatives for copying a file:

1. On Unix, you can use [`os.link`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.link).
2. On Windows, you can use a function like this:

   ```
   def CreateHardLink(src, dst):
       import ctypes 
       if not ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateHardLinkA(dst, src, 0):
           raise OSError
   ```

   (Disclaimer: I haven't tested it. The idea is to use the kernel32 API.)
3. If all this fails, you can still make a regular file copy (for example, with `shutil.copy2`).

Then, you can test these 3 functions at the beginning of the script with a temporary file (to be deleted afterwards). The first of these 3 functions that succeeds (that is, the first one that raises no `Exception`) is a good candidate for making the actual backup copies.

This idea follows a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), where you have to select a function that takes the source and destination filenames and makes the best effort to make the copy the way you want it.

Let me add one more thing: Detecting the filesystem in order to choose a copying strategy is not a very good practice in the same way that detecting browsers is not a good practice to do different things in Javascript. It's always best to try to use a feature and be prepared to catch exceptions or handle errors in order to produce an alternative result.

Comment: I'm using a combination of 1 and 2 already, and don't really want to fall back to regular copy. However, the browsers argument is a very good one... hmm... time for a rethink. Thanks for the input!